# Can anyone lead me to DEFINE assertions documentation for regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, assertions

I stumbled upon [this nice blog post by nikic](http://nikic.github.com/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html) titled *The true power of regular expressions*. I saw that regex of him using a DEFINE assertion to create a regular expression that matches an email in a RFC conformant way. The named captures are nice, but what I'm really wondering about is some documentation on the DEFINE assertion. Simplified example:

```
/(?(DEFINE)(?<NUM>[0-9]))^(?&NUM)$/
```

A quick search through my *Mastering Regular Expressions* book did not yield any fast results. Google left me empty handed and a test online with ideone lead to the result, that DEFINE is most probably some keyword to define assertions as I can't replace the word with e.g. FOOBAR. ;-) Links to the ideone test: [matching](http://ideone.com/eNDqz) vs. [non-matching](http://ideone.com/plXWY)

Any explanations, search keywords, hints or links to some nice documentation are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(DEFINE)` works as a way of defining named subpatterns. In your example above, you are defining the `NUM` subpattern, then using it `(?&NUM)`. In the linked example by nikic, a whole bunch of named sub-patterns are defined using each other, which cumulates in `?&addr_spec`.

As you've found, searching for the word "define" isn't easy. I've found a couple of references to get you started:

- [Perl Language reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28R%29)
- [Perl Regex Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Defining-named-patterns)
- [Gnome Regex details](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-regex-syntax.html#id394021)
- [Define Grammars in Regex](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1479)